# How to return result from node-memcached get function?

Tags: node.js

node memcached have a function `get` to retrieve memcachd key value for e.g.:

```
memcached.get( "hello",function( err, result ){
if( err ) console.error( err );
this.r = result;
console.dir( result );
memcached.end();});
```

The second argument in the function is the callback function 
inside the callback function I can log the value of my key easily. 
I tried to assign a property `r` to `memcached` and when I try to log the `memcached.r` outside `get` function `undefined` result occurs.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Although `this` looks like a variable and often behaves like one, it isn't truly a variable and thus does not behave like one in closures. When you've got one function nested inside another, the inner function gets a completely new version of `this` which is very unlikely to point to the same thing as the outer function's `this`.

Therefore, if you need to refer to an outer function's `this` inside an inner function, you have to first copy it into a true variable (most people like to call it `self` but some prefer `that`) and then refer to that variable in the inner function.

In your case, however, you've already got a real variable, namely `memcached`, that you can assign to, so just replace `this` with `memcached` in your callback. It's a properly-scoped outer variable of the closure created by your callback (as can be seen by the fact that you can use `memcached.end()` in it).

[Update to include correctly formatted version of your code mentioned in comment]

```
memcached.get = function get(key, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(key)) return this.getMulti.apply(this, arguments);
  this.command(function getCommand (noreply) {
    return { key: key , callback: callback ,
      validate: [['key', String], ['callback', Function]] ,
      type: 'get' , command: 'get ' + key };
  });
};
```

It looks like you're trying to call several functions asynchronously and expecting to `return` a value from them. That simply won't work.

Comment: ok , i use initialize connection first in `initial.js` file the call `require` function to this file with var `INIT` , i try to `INIT.memcached.r = result` in the inner function and call it outside but did not work too

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, though it's likely just a problem of poor translation. If you can find someone who's proficient in both English and your native language, and who understands programming, try running what you're saying past him/her and post what they have to say.

Comment: fine sorry for my poor lang but i'll make it more clear . in node memcached first you should connect to memcached server then do your query .what i've done is to write connection code in file called `initial.js` then create a file called `test.js` in this file i use `INIT = require('initial')` to use my memcahed connection and query for a key using `INIT.memcached.get` which work fine if i log result inside callback function but when i try to assign 'result` argument of the call back function to `INIT.memcached.r` then log it outside `get` function `undefined` result occur.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed some more of your code. Also, which particular `memcached` module are you using (there seem to be quite a few of them around)?

Comment: fine this is the memcached i used for node js [link](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached)

Comment: Unfortunately, someone seems to have deleted your second comment (the one that actually has the link) thinking it was a duplicate; I was just sort of glancing when I first saw it and now when I've got time to look at it, it's gone. In the meantime, please show some of the code surrounding the code that you've already shown (just enough to provide better context).

Comment: fine this is the `get` function `memcached.get = function get(key, callback) { if (Array.isArray(key)) return this.getMulti.apply(this, arguments); this.command(function getCommand (noreply) { return { key: key , callback: callback , validate: [['key', String], ['callback', Function]] , type: 'get' , command: 'get ' + key }; }); };` link for node memcached is [memcached.js](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/blob/master/lib/memcached.js)

Comment: i think it's related to asynchronous request and callback